# Understanding CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync behaviour

Tags: c#, windows, webview, webview2

I have an app with custom webview runtime installed near the exectuable.
In order to reproduce some user issue I did the following experiment:

I removed `msedgewebview2.exe` and started the app.

`env = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(browserExecutableFolder, EnvHelper.AppLocalFolder).Result;`

This line succeded but the next line `await WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);` faild with exception

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)`

That was expected.

Then I manually recovered `msedgewebview2.exe` to `browserExecutableFolder` and called the same function without restarting the app. It failed again with the same exception even though `msedgewebview2.exe` is available.

Does it mean that WebView runtime caches that information after the first `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync`. If the file is missing during the first call then it will not check again during next calls ?

I have also tried to call `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(browserExecutableFolder, EnvHelper.AppLocalFolder)` with different `EnvHelper.AppLocalFolder` every time but again the same result.

Can somebody explain this behaviour? Is it possible to disable caching result of the first call of `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync` and make it check again during every call.

Answers to the comment qustions:

> What kind of application is this?

It is WPF app.

> Are you using a packed fixed version?

Yes. At this moment it is version `"101.0.1210.47"`

> What is browserExecutableFolder set to?

Since now I have run the app using debugger it is `C:\repo\App\bin\x64\Debug\WebView2`

> Why aren't you awaiting .CreateAsync(), while you appear to be
> awaiting .EnsureCoreWebView2Async(),: these are usually called one
> after the other --

I just changed it to

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER", C:\repo\App\bin\x64\Debug\WebView2);`

`coreWebView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(browserExecutableFolder, EnvHelper.AppLocalFolder, new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions(null, null, "101.0.1210.47"));`

And it doesn't change anything.(

Comment: What kind of application is this? Are you using a packed fixed version? What is `browserExecutableFolder` set to? Why aren't you awaiting `.CreateAsync()`, while you appear to be awaiting `.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()`,: these are usually called one after the other -- Did you try to set the env variable, calling `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER", [Path to the Executable]);` (-> first question)? -- Did you try to set and pass to `.CreateAsync()` a `CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` object that specifies (third parameter) the fixed version you're targeting?

Comment: @Jimi I answered your questions inside the post.

Comment: Can you post your code as code, to give some context, instead of posting pieces of it here and there? --  What .Net version are you targeting? -- It looks like your target CPU is x64; is the corresponding `WebView2Loader.dll` reachable there? You should have copies in the `\runtimes` folder. Try to make a copy of it (x64) and add it to the root folder of your app (*) (unless a copy of the same bitness is not already there) -- Since it's a WPF app, you don't need `.SetEnvironmentVariable()` -- I cannot replicate, but I don't have that version.

Comment: (*) A copy because, even if this mandatory only if you have a native app, I remember that a similar problem could arise (file not found) up to some version (I don't remember which one) also in a .Net app.

Comment: @Jimi duplicating WebView2Loader.dll is good idea, I will try it.